# Data recovery from old windows SATA drives using Ubuntu

Tags: partitioning, ssd, data-recovery, windows-xp

My data storage disk crashed with a hardware failure and the data isn't worth the 500+$ it would take to repair it. I have most of it on two old windows XP hard drives I pulled out of my old PCs and want to copy the data to a new SSD drive.

My issue is this: My new windows box doesn't support USB2 which is what my external case for the old SATA drives uses so I want to use my UBUNTU box to copy the data to the SSD. I would also like to back up the media I have on the Ubuntu box since that is what I use for video and music editing.

I'm assuming I should make the SSD drive NTFS, but what commands would I use in Ubuntu to copy from one external drive to another given they are both NTFS?
Would a simple cp command do the trick?

I feel like it can't be that easy.

Comment: Almost all USB 3+ ports will happily talk to USB 2 accessories.  Have you tried it?

Comment: You can not copy files from a failed HDD, because a hardware failure usually leads to read/write failures. Obviously, commands are no magic, and will not make a difference in case of an unreadable HDD.

Answer (score 0):

First off, your new Windows computer supports USB2 (unless it's a "new" computer from your Grandma who purchased it in 2001) but if you must use Ubuntu

1. Make sure your external hard drive is mounted
2. Make sure you have permissions
3. Just to be safe, you can use `sudo cp -r ~/"mount folder"` to new drive

I typically create a mount point in Ubuntu in case I want to mount it again in the future and make it easy to get to

1. `mkdir external-hdd`
2. `sudo fdisk -l`
3. `sudo mount /dev/sdx ~/external-hdd`
4. copy files through GUI if using full desktop or `sudo cp -r ~/external-hdd ~/newfolder`